# Stripe Webhook with Shipping, Billing, and Order information

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to use Stripe Webhooks to get all the information on orders being placed and use it to fulfill my orders. However, I can't seem to find the right event / trigger that contains all the information I need. The two I've found so far that are pretty good are `order.payment_succeeded` and `payment_intent.succeeded`.

`order.payment_succeeded` has all the info I need except it doesn't have the buyer's billing address / info.

`payment_intent.succeeded` on the other hand has all the info except for the line items / list of products ordered.

Is there an event that has billing, shipping, and order info all in one? If not which one of these two events happens first? At least I can store the data somehow and update it based on info coming in...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the billing information you would need to expand the charge object linked on the order [1][2] when you receive the `order.payment_succeeded` event. The shipping address is part of the event Order payload [3].

All that being said, the Orders API is officially deprecated. Our recommendation if possible, and if you would like to charge customers, collect their billing info [4] and shipping info [5] would be to use Stripe Checkout [6]. The events you will receive when a user successfully completes a checkout will include `checkout.session.completed` [7]. Using the payload of this event which is a Checkout Session object, you can query the API for the line items [8] that were included in the Checkout Session.

Events from Stripe do not have a guaranteed order [9] but an `order.payment_succeeded` would imply that the charge has succeeded.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/object#order_object-charge

[2]https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-billing_details

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/object#order_object-shipping

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-billing_address_collection

[5] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection

[6] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

[7] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed

[8] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items

[9] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering